# Up to what temperature can you work without damaging yourself?

Tags: environmental-conditions, safety, weather, heat-exhaustion, heatstroke

Currently here in the Netherlands we're having quite warm weather, I work in a greenhouse in which temperature's rise quite fast. I had to work in 40 degrees Celcius (104 Fahrenheit) last weekend. Upcoming weekend this might get up 47 degrees or 117 Fahrenheit, what I was wondering is how long can/may I work and do I damage myself if I work a full 8 hours?

My work consists of helping customers find things, refilling plants, watering plants and moving trees/heaving things (around 20kg/44 lbs) for a full 8 hours.

If it's not too busy at our greenhouse shop I can usually take a 15 minute break around 3:00PM and that's all I get for the day which is enough although I wonder if I should take precautions to make sure my body stays healthy.

So basically I'm interested in  how long can a human being work in a store where it is 47 degrees C? I can understand that this is quite a broad question but I'm looking for a general answer and what precautions I can take. Would there be any side effects?

Comment: Quite a lot of this will be your personal response, everyone will vary. One very important thing will be to keep as hydrated as possible, especially in a greenhouse where humidity is also likely to be very high.

Comment: I suppose this does depend on person to person, I only get half a liter of water from 7AM - 3PM and then during my break. Would this be enough or should I ask for an extra break? I myself cant handle heat that well, mainly because of the humidity.

Comment: A half liter of water for 8 hours of work in those temperatures is wholly inadequate. Is there some reason you can't bring additional water with you?

Comment: Well I cant because I work in a store, i'd have to take it with me all day wich is not allowed at work